# True or false: If log f (n) ∈ Θ(log g(n)), then f (n) ∈ Θ(g(n)).

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

It seems true and I can find cases that satisfy this statement. But how to formally prove it? Thank you.

Comment: Take $f=n, g=n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.

---

Try proving it by unfolding the definitions. From
$$c'·\log g≤ \log f ≤ c·\log g \quad\text{eventually}$$
(with some $c, c' > 0$), by applying $\exp$, you get
$$g^{c'} ≤ f ≤ g^c\quad\text{eventually}.$$
If $c = c' = 1$, everything seems fine. But what if not?

---

*Counterexample*. Say $f = \operatorname{id}_ℕ$ and $g (n) = n^2$ (so $g = f·f$). Then $\log g = 2 \log f$, but $f \notin Θ(g)$.

Comment: The asymptotics $x(n)=\Theta(y(n))$ is defined as the property that $cy(n)\leqslant x(n)\leqslant Cy(n)$ for every $n$ large enough, not that $cy(n)-d\leqslant x(n)\leqslant C\log g(n)+D$ for every $n$. The two versions are equivalent if $x(n)\to\infty$ or $y(n)\to\infty$, but not otherwise.

Comment: @Did Okay, I was thinking of the characterization for maps $ℕ → ℕ$ (in which case I believe they are equivalent). I updated my answer accordingly now.